# How to match only the first occurrence of String B after finding String A

Tags: php, regex

I have to do a mass search-and-replace with Regex on a bunch of Wordpress pages.

I have a content block where I need to replace two identical strings with different values. Therefore, I need to use Regex to find and match only the first occurrence of a string.

Everything I've done so far matches both occurrences. Here's what I have... trying to only match the first occurrence of a string after a certain string. However, the following regex matches both occurrences.

`(item="Finish")*(8678)`

I would like to see only the first occurrence of that string be matched.

https://regexr.com/4di9c

Here's the source string:

`[vc_row class="options-tabs-section"][vc_column][vc_tta_tabs active_section="1"][vc_tta_section title="Finish" tab_id="finisha2ec-a4f1"][vc_media_grid element_width="3" item="8678" grid_id="vc_gid:1557243701236-783a77b3-2fb2-8" include="717,716,715,714,713,712,711,709,708,707"][/vc_tta_section][vc_tta_section title="Glass" tab_id="glassa2ec-a4f1"][vc_media_grid element_width="3" item="8656" grid_id="vc_gid:1557243701239-312d0b1e-25cd-9" include="964,972,724,971,969,968,967,966,965"][/vc_tta_section][vc_tta_section title="Handles" tab_id="handlesa2ec-a4f1"][vc_media_grid element_width="3" item="8678" grid_id="vc_gid:1557243701240-a408e67a-7aab-7" include="8661,8667,8660,8664,8665,8663,8662,8668,8666,8669"][/vc_tta_section][/vc_tta_tabs][/vc_column][/vc_row]`

EDIT: I realize I'm probably thinking too hard here. Here's what I did that got me the answer I needed... Probably didn't need to do regex. I simply removed the global flag and went step-by-step:

```
<?php


$input='[vc_row class="options-tabs-section"][vc_column][vc_tta_tabs active_section="1"][vc_tta_section title="Finish" tab_id="finish84e3-bb24"][vc_media_grid element_width="3" item="4566" grid_id="vc_gid:1551131488971-e1d811df-ddaf-8" include="717,716,715,714,713,712,711,709,708,707"][/vc_tta_section][vc_tta_section title="Glass" tab_id="glass84e3-bb24"][vc_media_grid element_width="3" item="174" grid_id="vc_gid:1551131488974-85d653d4-4558-1" include="964,972,724,971,969,968,967,966,965"][/vc_tta_section][vc_tta_section title="Handles" tab_id="handles84e3-bb24"][vc_media_grid element_width="3" item="174" grid_id="vc_gid:1551131488975-8b255d93-ab50-6" include="961,960,959,913,912,911,910,909,908,907"][/vc_tta_section][/vc_tta_tabs][/vc_column][/vc_row]';

$output=preg_replace('/961,960,959,913,912,911,910,909,908,907/', '8661,8667,8660,8664,8665,8663,8662,8668,8666,8669', $input );

$output=preg_replace('/4566/', '8678', $output);
$output=preg_replace('/174/', '8656', $output);
$output=preg_replace('/174/', '8678', $output);

echo $output;
echo "\n";
```

Comment: Please add expected output and the actual code that you are using in PHP/JS.

Comment: If you only want the first occurrence, then don't use a global regex?

Comment: You mean something like `(?:title="Finish").*?(8678)` This captures the first `8678` after `title="Finish"`. Apologies if I misunderstood your question. https://regexr.com/4diap

Comment: Just do not use `g` modifier in online testers, it matches "globally", all occurrences. It is a JS flag, in PHP, just use `preg_match` for first occurrence. With `preg_replace`, there is a `limit` argument, too.

Comment: @BlackPearl Yes except that I only need the "8678", not everything between the title="Finish" and the 8678.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew This is the best answer, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There needs to be more information to properly answer your question, but if you are looking to match the first occurance and were to use [the preg_match() PHP function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php), you could do it like so:

```
preg_match('/(item="Finish")*(8678)/', $yourString, $matches);
var_dump($matches[0]);
```

[PHPFiddle](https://3v4l.org/U8u38)

Depending on what you are doing, this may not solve it, but most of the [PRCE/Regular Expression Functions in PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pcre.php) will use similar parameters and function in a similar way.